# Limiting Light class instantiations

Tags: c++, oop, opengl, static, limit

I have a class 'Light' which functions out of the box, but I know that OpenGL only allows a finite number of lights to be active at any one time. According to `glGetIntegerfv(GL_MAX_LIGHTS, ..)` the max lights is 8, so I should only allow the Light class be instantiated up to 8 times whether in compile time or run.

I have tried a method of trying to solve the problem:

```
int Light::sCounter = 0;

Light::Light() : // initialiser-list
{
    sCounter++;

    if (sCounter > getMaxLightCount())
        // do something, but what?
}
```

Where sCounter is a `static int` and `getMaxLightCount()` calls the foresaid OpenGL function. If the counter is above the maximum number of lights, then something should happen; but I don't how I should respond. I can't return NULL or something in a constructor, but I have been looking at exceptions to solve the problem; though I generally dislike exceptions since it over-complicates the situation. I have also looked at implementing a Manager class, but that would make things counter-intuitive since it effectively means a user wouldn't be calling the Light class, but the Manager thereof.

What options do I have in limiting the number of instantiations of the Light class, and which solution would be effective in being intuitive for reuse?

Comment: I would manage the count externally

Comment: So, a manager class would do the counting you say?

Comment: This is a good situation where a pool set to a configurable limit would be useful. It would also be beneficial to have a manager that would keep track of the pool. http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not too restrictive you could prevent instantiations of the `Light` class except when using a *factory*. The following example requires C++11 but could be made to work without it (albeit with more work, using boost, etc).

Even if the following example isn't sufficient perhaps it gives you some ideas.

### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class Light
{
public:
    using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<Light, std::function<void (Light*)>>;

    static void destroyLight(Ptr light)
    {
        // Do nothing, 'light' will be deleted when it falls out of scope
    }

    static Ptr createLight()
    {
        if (sInstanceCount < MAX_INSTANCE_COUNT)
        {
            ++sInstanceCount;
            return Ptr(new Light(), &Light::destroyLightImpl );
        }
        else
        {
            return Ptr();
        }
    }

private:
    Light() {} // Prevent others from creating instances
    ~Light() {} // Prevent others from deleting instances

    static void destroyLightImpl(Light* light)
    {
        delete light;
        --sInstanceCount;
    }

    static const int MAX_INSTANCE_COUNT = 3;
    static int sInstanceCount;
};

int Light::sInstanceCount = 0;

int main()
{
    Light::Ptr light1 = Light::createLight();
    Light::Ptr light2 = Light::createLight();
    std::cout << light1.get() << "\n";
    std::cout << light2.get() << "\n";

    Light::Ptr light3 = Light::createLight();
    Light::Ptr light4 = Light::createLight();
    std::cout << light3.get() << "\n";
    std::cout << light4.get() << "\n";

    Light::destroyLight(std::move(light3));
    Light::Ptr light5 = Light::createLight();
    std::cout << light5.get() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output

You can see here the first 3 instantiations succeed but the 4th doesn't. However, the 5th does work because the 3rd light has been deleted.

```
005872C0
005872F0
00587320
00000000
00587320
```

Comment: Why pass a pointer to the destroyFoo function when we can call it from outside the class?

Comment: @Poriferous I believe that's the function signature required for a custom deleter in `std::unique_ptr` (see the 'Type requirement' section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)). But you're correct it doesn't make sense for that function to be public and I updated it to be private.

Comment: You use braces to demonstrate how light3 is deleted; otherwise to do the equivalent would be to use light3.get_deleter()?

Comment: @Poriferous This was really just an example to give you an idea for how might handle it. If you wanted more control over the lifetime of the object then perhaps you'd add a public function which takes a `Light::Ptr`. I'll update the example to show this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to have whatever class is creating the light maintain the count rather than trying to handle it within the `Light` class itself.

If you have many light-owners it would probably be best to set up some sort of pool from which lights can be obtained, and if desired you could even create a mechanism by which one client could request different clients to relinquish lights.